# Reloaded list when selected row in primefaces datatable

Tags: primefaces, datatable

I'm doing an example to retrieve a list of data from a mysql database. All this works fine. 
The problem is occurring when I load the page and the method of data recovery runs twice the first time the page loads. 
When I select a record from dataTable method that retrieves data from the list are executed many times depending on the selected record. Example, if I select the registration No. 4, it runs 4 times until it reaches the selected index to show the detail of that record. 
Any idea Behavior ?. How to solve the method is run once? 
Primefaces 5.0.RC2 + Spring4, JPA, Annotations

```
package com.maosdel.rgi.web.controllers;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.maosdel.rgi.dto.OperatorDTO;
import com.maosdel.rgi.model.exception.RgiBusinessException;
import com.maosdel.rgi.model.services.OperatorService;

@SessionScoped
@Component("operatorBean")
public class OperatorBean implements Serializable {

static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OperatorBean.class);

private static final long serialVersionUID = -491242034992898914L;

@Autowired(required = true)
private OperatorService operatorService;

private OperatorDTO operatorSelected;
private List<OperatorDTO> operatorList;

public OperatorBean() {
    logger.info("OperatorBean instantiated...");
}

private List<OperatorDTO> loadAllOperators() {
    List<OperatorDTO> result = null;
    try {
        result = (List<OperatorDTO>) operatorService.getAllOperatorsHQL();
    } catch (RgiBusinessException e) {
        logger.error("Error recuperando registros... " + e);
    }
    return result;
}

public List<OperatorDTO> getOperatorList() {
    operatorList = loadAllOperators(); 
    return operatorList;
}

public OperatorDTO getOperatorSelected() {
    try {
        if (null != operatorSelected) {
            operatorSelected = operatorService.getOperatorById(operatorSelected.getId());
        }

    } catch (RgiBusinessException e) {
        logger.error("Error recuperando operador con Id: " + 2 + " Error: "
                + e);
    }
    return operatorSelected;
}

public void setOperatorSelected(OperatorDTO operatorSelected) {
    this.operatorSelected = operatorSelected;
}

}
```

xhtml page

```
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/defaultTemplate.xhtml">
<ui:define name="content">
    <h:form id="operatorFrm">
        <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true" />

        <p:dataTable var="operator" value="#{operatorBean.operatorList}"
            paginator="true" rows="10" rowKey="#{operator.id}"
            selectionMode="single">

            <f:facet name="header">
                Operadores
            </f:facet>

            <p:column headerText="Id">
                <h:outputText value="#{operator.id}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Code">
                <h:outputText value="#{operator.code}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Name">
                <h:outputText value="#{operator.name}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Last name">
                <h:outputText value="#{operator.lastName}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Data contract">
                <h:outputText value="#{operator.contractDate}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="State">
                <h:outputText value="#{operator.state}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column style="width:32px;text-align: center">
                <p:commandButton update=":operatorFrm:operatorDetail"
                    oncomplete="PF('operatorDlg').show()" icon="ui-icon-search"
                    title="View">
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{operator}"
                        target="#{operatorBean.operatorSelected}" />
                </p:commandButton>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>


        <p:dialog header="Operator Info" widgetVar="operatorDlg" modal="true"
            showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" resizable="false">

            <p:outputPanel id="operatorDetail" style="text-align:center;">
                <p:panelGrid columns="2"
                    rendered="#{not empty operatorBean.operatorSelected}"
                    columnClasses="label,value">

                    <f:facet name="header">
                    </f:facet>

                    <h:outputText value="Id:" />
                    <h:outputText value="#{operatorBean.operatorSelected.id}" />

                    <h:outputText value="Code" />
                    <h:outputText value="#{operatorBean.operatorSelected.code}" />

                    <h:outputText value="Name" />
                    <h:outputText value="#{operatorBean.operatorSelected.name}" />

                    <h:outputText value="Last name" />
                    <h:outputText value="#{operatorBean.operatorSelected.lastName}" />

                    <h:outputText value="Data contract" />
                    <h:outputText value="#{operatorBean.operatorSelected.contractDate}" />

                    <h:outputText value="State" />
                    <h:outputText value="#{operatorBean.operatorSelected.state}" />

                </p:panelGrid>
            </p:outputPanel>
        </p:dialog>
    </h:form>
</ui:define>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<OperatorDTO> getOperatorList() {
    operatorList = loadAllOperators(); 
    return operatorList;
}
```

This is your problem. The datatable component is calling the getter for the list, which i also presume is making a database call. This is also considered as bad design, since accessor methods should not do operations like that.

So what you need to do is initialize the list and load the data at the beginning and not in your getter.

Also you can take a look at the showcase if you hadn't already, where the list is initialized with a @PostConstruct.

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml

**Update:**

```
 <h:outputText value="Id:" />
       <h:outputText value="#{operatorBean.operatorSelected.id}" />
       <h:outputText value="#{operatorBean.operatorSelected.code}" />
       <h:outputText value="#{operatorBean.operatorSelected.name}" />
       <h:outputText value="#{operatorBean.operatorSelected.lastName}" />
       <h:outputText value="#{operatorBean.operatorSelected.contractDate}" />
       <h:outputText value="#{operatorBean.operatorSelected.state}" />
```

Each line of the above code is calling the getter getOperatorSelected() in your backing bean, which is why the method is executed multiple times, this is normal behavior. However your method is again doing unnecessary operations. The accessor method should only do one thing, that is return the value.

```
public OperatorDTO getOperatorSelected() {
    return operatorSelected;
}
```

You don't have to manually do the lookup using your service method, the datatable will handle that for you.

Comment: Thank you Emil,
I have created a init method with PostConstruct annotation and work fine.
But there is one problem when I select one row to view its detail and the method getOperatorSelected() runs multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot selection tag

```
selection="#{operatorBean.operatorSelected}"
```

can you try below code?

```
<p:dataTable var="operator" value="#{operatorBean.operatorList}"
        paginator="true" rows="10" rowKey="#{operator.id}"
        selectionMode="single" selection="#{operatorBean.operatorSelected}">
```